# Embedded Shiny app in RMarkdown deploys successfully but then times out as "not found"

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, flexdashboard

I have a flexdashboard with a very simple embedded shiny app here: https://iser.shinyapps.io/fuel_treatment_dashboard

While the static elements of the dashboard are fine, the shiny app typically loads successfully for about one minute, then disconnects and the error message "NOT FOUND" appears. If I reboot the app from the shinyapps.io dashboard, it works again, for a minute or so, then the error message reappears.

Here is my deployment log:

[Deployment Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mx6Z.png)

Here are my settings on shinyapps.io: [shinyapps.io settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1Uko.png)

Here is the code for the shiny element, which is just a drop down datatable filter:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

choices = df$name
choices <- as.vector(choices)
  
#df <- read.fst("data/fst_files/fuel_treatment_subset.fst")

ui <- fillPage(
  

  # Select input for list of cars to filter
  selectInput("filter", "Filter by Fuel Treatment:",
              choices = unique(df$name)),
  
  # Table output to display filtered data
 div(style="height: 900px; overflow-y: auto", tableOutput("filtered_data"))
  
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Read in the data frame
  df3 <- by_owner
  
  # Filter dataframe based on user input
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    df3 %>%
      filter(name %in% input$filter)
  })
  
  # Render the filtered dataframe as a table
  
  output$filtered_data <- renderTable({
    filtered_data()
  })
  
}
# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I tried rebooting the app from shinyapps.io dashboard but this only works temporarily.  I also adjusted the timeout settings on the shinyapps.io dashboard, but they seem to have no effect.

Comment: Where is `by_owner` and `df` defined? You've commented out the line that reads in the data, and it also looks like you're trying to use a column from `df` before that line.

Does it run fine locally (is it an app issue, or an issue when deploying to shinyapps.io?)

Comment: runs fine locally, yes.  by_owner is defined in previous sections of dashboard, which is about 900 lines of code so I didn't include it.  It's an issue when deploying to shinyapps.io.